# How to get the output predictions in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

As the title says, I'm trying to grab the actual prediction in my TensorFlow model. The issue is that I don't understand how to grab the prediction even though there are multiple answers already. I don't understand what data the pred.eval or the session functions need, and I was hoping someone here could explain it.

The code I'm using is here:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as plt
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    input_layer=tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu
    )
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu
    )
    pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pool2_flat=tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

    dense=tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    dropout=tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    )
    logits=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

    tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
    tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
    loss=tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op=optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step()
        )
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
    mnist=tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
    train_data=mnist.train.images
    train_labels=np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
    eval_data=mnist.test.images
    eval_labels=np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

    mnist_classifier=tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model"
    )

    tensors_to_log={"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook=tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

    train_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": train_data},
        y=train_labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True
    )
    mnist_classifier.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=20000,
        hooks=[logging_hook]
    )
    eval_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": eval_data},
        y=eval_labels,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False
    )
    eval_results=mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()`
```

What do I do in this situation?

Any advice is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: its an MNIST problem and shouldn't you  be feeding an image of a digit and see the prediction, I do not understand your exact question

Comment: Hey my question is how do I check my actual prediction with this code, sorry if my question was unclear

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input data for which you want to get predictions is called `predict_data` (and here you can use `train_data` or `eval_data` if that's what you're interested in), you would do

```
pred_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x': predict_data}, shuffle=False)
predictor = list(mnist_classifier.predict(pred_input_fn))
```

At this point, `predictor` is a list of dictionaries mapping `'classes'` to the predicted classes and `'probabilities'` to the associated probabilities. The sort of results you can get out of this are exactly the ones you specify as `predictions` in `cnn_model_fn`.

Comment: I'm really new to tensorflow so I don't really understand; how do I get a prediction from this list? For example I want this program to tell me what it number it predicted from the test images.

Comment: The data structure you get out is a list of dictionaries, so at that point you will not be using TensorFlow anymore. Rather, to get the predicted class for the first element of `predict_data`, you would use `predictor[0]['classes']`. I would suggest getting familiar with an interactive environment (such as [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab)) or a debugger (such as what comes bundled with [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) to become able to investigate what sort of things are possible. This one-time investment pays off almost immediately.